# 'CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use NSURLSession API for http requests

Tags: objective-c, deprecated

I got some code I would like to update to undeprecated, but I don't know how,
here is the code:

```
//
    // Create the read stream that will receive data from the HTTP request
    //
    stream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(NULL, message);
    CFRelease(message);
    
    //
    // Enable stream redirection
    //
    if (CFReadStreamSetProperty(
        stream,
        kCFStreamPropertyHTTPShouldAutoredirect,
        kCFBooleanTrue) == false)
    {
        [self presentAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"File Error", @"Errors", nil)
                            message:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Unable to configure network read stream.", @"Errors", nil)];
        return NO;
    }
```

any idea?

Thank you!

Jean

Comment: describe a little more about your problem

Comment: Ok, I développed an app for an associative radio. I made the app with a project https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer to make a part of the app. the problem is that some part of code is deprecated. I would like to replace it by other code, but, don't know how... I did it with others parts easier, but there, I can't...